# Is there a Plunkr-like Web site for node.js applications?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, plunker

I need to post some node, express, mongoose code online as demo for a StackOverflow discussion. Plunkr does not accept node emulation afaik. Any ideas where to host a demo app with live editor of the code?

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://jsapp.us/ to run sample node code.

Comment: Nice.. do you know if I can install e.g. https://github.com/mccormicka/Mockgoose to simulate a MongoDB database on there?

Comment: Nooo idea - sorry. There is a built in DB component - might help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Plunkr sorry but judging from the design goals that are on their front page you can user [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) to achieve similar results (albeit in a slightly different way).

It's really easy, have a free option, and you push via git repository, so it is a no brainer to upload your code iterations to your instance, just commit and push your changes to whatever repository you use.

Comment: Possible for others to alter code online? Also, if you don't know Plunkr yet, you should get to know it, it is really common around here :)